# What are 'abstract' functions in PHP and when are they used?

Tags: php, class, oop, extend

I know that abstract classes are only meant to be used are parent classes and cannot have their own instances but what are abstract functions/methods? What are their uses? When are they used(an example)? and how does their scope(public, private, protected) works?

Use the following code as an example.

```
abstract class parentTest{

    //abstract protected function f1();
    //abstract public function f2();
    //abstract private function f3();

}

class childTest extends parentTest{
    public function f1(){
        echo "This is the 'f1' function.<br />";
    }

    public function f2(){
        echo "This is the 'f2' function.<br />";
    }
    protected function f3(){
        echo "This is the 'f3' function.<br />";
    }
}

$foo = new childTest();
$foo->f1();
```

Comment: Abstract classes are like interface classes where you also define a few methods. http://php.net/abstract

Comment: I suggest you read some getting started tutorial about oop programming in php or in general. This question is answered in there, for certain. Including examples.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract function is a method signature that defines a contract in the super (abstract) class. That contract must be implemented by any subclasses. The method implementation's visibility in the subclasses must be the same or a less restrictive one than that of the superclass. Please, take a look at [Class Abstraction - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Note: visibility is not the same as scope. Visibility is about data hiding in the context of OOP. Scope is more general. It's about where (in the code) a variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract methods are theoritically used when you want to share a method between inheriting instances. For instance, say you have a abstract class that represents a view, and each inheriting class will have to render something, you can define the method in the parent abstract class, and all child will have access to it:

```
abstract class Template {
    public function render($template) {
        include($template);
    }
}
class SiteView extends Template {
    protected $title = "default title";
}
$siteView = new SiteView();
$siteView->render('path/to/site/template.html');
```

To improve this, you can also use an interface and start type-hinting your classes:

```
interface Renderer {
    public function render($template);
}
abstract class Template implements Renderer {
    public function render($template) {
        include($template);
    }
}
class SiteView extends Template {
    protected $title = "default title";
    protected $body= "default body";
}
class Controller {
    private $view;
    public function __construct(Renderer $view) {
        $this->view = $view;
    }
    public function show() {
        $this->view->render('path/to/site/template.html');
    }
}
$siteView = new SiteView();
$controller = new Controller($siteView);
$controller->show();
```

Notice how afterwards the controller is decoupled from the abstract and concrete class, while the abstract class allows you to share the render function with inheriting Views. Should you decide to create other abstract class representing other ways to render stuff, the controller would continue working.

for the records, the template would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= $this->title ?></title>
</head>
<body><?= $this->body ?></body>
</html>
```